# What to do with extundelete recovered files

Tags: linux, restore, deleted-files, extundelete

So, i accidentally delete my files. I attempt to recover files using extundelete with --restore-all options. Inside the RECOVERED_FILES directory i got files.xxxxx which i think is inode file.

My question is what to do with file.xxxxx file ?